# Drawing circles using 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Trying to draw circles via loop but get only one circle. What i'm doing wrong?

```
var ss_links_canvas = document.getElementById("ss_links_canvas");
ss_links_canvas.width = images.length * 41;
ss_links_canvas.height = 25;
var ss_links = ss_links_canvas.getContext("2d");

for (i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
    ss_links.beginPath();
    ss_links.fillStyle="white";
    ss_links.arc(12,12+i*41,5,0,2*Math.PI);
    ss_links.fill();
    ss_links.closePath();
}
```

'images' is a array with 4 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're drawing them vertically rather than horizontal so the rest of the circles fall outside of the canvas change:

```
ss_links.arc(12,12+i*41,5,0,2*Math.PI);
```

to:

```
ss_links.arc(12+i*41,12,5,0,2*Math.PI);
```